# GoMage_Checkout_Helper_Data not found in public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento

One of our sites is generating the follow error:

Fatal error: Class 'GoMage_Checkout_Helper_Data' not found in /home/dealsonb/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

And I'm stumped as to why this has suddenly started happening.

The site had been working fine for months, and it's just happened over the weekend.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The module is not finding the helper file, so there is some error in your xml code. Find the module location,

`app > code > [CodePool] > GoMage > Checkout > etc`. Then open the `config.xml` and post the code within the  `<helpers>        </helpers>` and `<frontend></frontend>` tags. I believe the issue lies somewhere here.

Also, make sure that you have a `Data.php` file within this location `app > code > [CodePool] > GoMage > Checkout > Helper.`

Answer (score 0):

First check that there must be some code like this in app/code//GoMage/Checkout/etc:

```
<global>
<helpers>
<checkout>
<class>GoMage_Checkout_Helper</class>
</checkout>
</helpers>
</global>
```

if not, then copy it and past into config.xml of module.

Next check whether there is app/code//GoMage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php

and it contains code like this:

```
<?php
class GoMage_Checkout_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
```

If the extension was removed then check there are some calls to helper functions in your code.

Removed the code `Mage::helper('checkout')`.

Please let me know your review after checking above.